# Python3 zipfile writestr, UserWarning: Duplicate name

Tags: python, python-3.x

For each modification, add one to the number of files that have been modified

```
In [1]: import zipfile

In [2]: with zipfile.ZipFile('demo.zip', 'a') as z:
   ...:     files = z.namelist()
   ...:     print(files)
   ...:     i = z.getinfo('1.txt')
   ...:     z.writestr(i, 'test')
   ...:
   ...:
['1.txt', '__MACOSX/', '__MACOSX/._1.txt']
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py:1355: UserWarning: Duplicate name: '1.txt'
  return self._open_to_write(zinfo, force_zip64=force_zip64)

In [3]: z = zipfile.ZipFile('demo.zip', 'r')

In [4]: print(z.namelist())
['1.txt', '__MACOSX/', '__MACOSX/._1.txt', '1.txt']
```

After modification, there are two '1.txt' in z.namelist(),
but when I extract demo.zip, there is only one '1.txt'

Comment: The double file entry is  a rather surprising feature of zip file that usually creates troubles when extracting.